# Inverse of $y= x^{3} +x+1$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

Can you help me find the inverse function for  $y= x^3 +x+1$? This question proposed by one of my friends and I don't know the real source of the problem.
We can't use Cardano's method for solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Cardano works, and is the only thing that will work... $x^3 + x$ is always increasing, so you never get casus irreducibils  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano%27s_method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Inverse of $y=x^5-x^3+x$ in terms $y=$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543740/the-inverse-of-y-x5-x3x-in-terms-y)

Comment: @WillJagy: it is not *the only thing*. Lagrange inversion theorem applies, too. $$x=-\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{3k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k (1-y)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't know that one. Maybe I should have said only easy, closed form, finite number of terms, and so on.

Answer (score 8):

Why won't Cardano work?

---

I'll tackle this problem the algebraic way because it's the most straightforward, despite the intimidating algebra.

Replacing $x$ with $y$, we get$$y^3+y+1=x\quad\implies\quad y^3+y+1-x=0$$Now recall Cardano's formula for the cubic $x^3+qx+r=0$ who has the real root at$$x_1=\left\{-\frac r2+\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}+\left\{-\frac r2-\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}$$Substituting $q=1$ and $r=1-x$ gives$$\begin{align*}y=\sqrt[3]{-\frac {1-x}2+\sqrt{\frac {27x^2-54x+31}{108}}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac {1-x}2+\sqrt{\frac {27x^2-54x+31}{108}}}\end{align*}$$And that's your inverse! Here's a visual diagram in Desmos

[image: Inverse]

Comment: I'm pretty sure "can't" meant "not allowed to" in the question.

Comment: Notice that the square roots always come out real, as $27 x^2 - 54x + 31 >0$

Comment: "Can" means.. bending the numerical solution to an analytical one.

Comment: @WillJagy Oh... I see. In that case, I'll have to rework the answer.

Comment: Crescendo, I wouldn't worry about it. You gave a good answer. At the moment you have seven upvotes, so you have helped some people. My impression when an OP says a friend gave a question is that there is a minor contest somewhere that is being hidden. Add in an unrealistic restriction on techniques, for me that confirms it. You did a good job.

Comment: It's a very difficult way for decomposition of the original algebric expression.

Comment: @BarzanHayati Can you clarify that?

Answer (score -1):

Given

$$ y = x^3+x+1 $$

Interchange $x,y$ to see inverse function graph.

$$ x= y^3+y+1 $$

Using Cardano it is quite possible to find the solution $f(x)$ in terms of $y$ *analytically.* There is one real root at $x=1$ coinciding at its inflection point.

Comment: Unfortunately your respond is not correct.